# How to include arg to Telegram bot?

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I want to include some arguments to some commands in my Telegram bot although I don't know how to make the Telegram Bot understand the arguments (numbers or strings). An example: `/myname John`, or `/age 34` and the bot replies with `"your name is John"` or `"your age is 34"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to access the messages text, which will be `/myname John`/`/age 34`, respectively. from there you can get the arguments.
Since you tagged PTB: when using [`Commandhandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.commandhandler.html) you can use [`CallbackContext.args`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html#telegram.ext.CallbackContext.args) as shortcut, as showcased [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Types-of-Handlers#commandhandlers-with-arguments).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: You are a life saver, it worked like a charm! I haven't seen Wiki before but I will make sure I will see it more often.